# Can I add an XML declaration to an XSLT output?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my current XML output:

```
    <EmployeeImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Employee>
    <EmployeeNumber>123</EmployeeNumber>
    <FirstName>Jose</FirstName>
    </Employee>
    </EmployeeImport>
```

and so on. What I would like to have my output is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <EmployeeImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Employee>
    <EmployeeNumber>123</EmployeeNumber>
    <FirstName>Jose</FirstName>
    </Employee>
    </EmployeeImport>
```

I would like to be able to add the first line to my output. In my XSLT, I have tried `&lt;`

to print "<" but it is interpreted just as `&lt;`. I have also tried `<xsl:text>`, but ran into the same issue. Is there a way to add this declaratory line to my XSLT?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [xsl:output](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#output).

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. So by defining the output, writing a declaration explicitly will never be necessary?

Comment: @AdamL - Correct. Also, when outputting XML 1.0 the declaration is not required. See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd for more details.

Comment: @AdamL, keep in mind that the XML declaration like other `xsl:output` properties is a serialization property, if the XSLT processor does serialize and is in charge of the serialization then, yes, with the right `xsl:output` (XML output method, omit-xml-declaration not explicitly set to yes) it will output the XML declaration. There are however scenarios or processor uses and API (`transformToDocument` in browsers) uses where the XSLT processor does not serialize or is not in charge of the serialization, in that case the `xsl:output` might not matter.